# Configure Iterative Closest Point PCL

Tags: android-ndk, point-cloud-library

I am having trouble configuring ICP in PCL 1.6(I use Android) and I believe that is the cause of an incorrect transformation matrix. What I've tried so far is this; 
Downsample the point clouds I use in ICP with the following code:

```
    pcl::VoxelGrid <pcl::PointXYZ> grid; 

    grid.setLeafSize(6, 6, 6); 
    grid.setInputCloud(output); 
    grid.filter(*tgt); 

    grid.setInputCloud(cloud_src); 
    grid.filter(*src);
```

Try to align the two point clouds with the following code :

```
pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ> icp; 
icp.setInputCloud(tgt); 
icp.setInputTarget(src); 
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> Final; 
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> transformedCloud; 
icp.setMaxCorrespondenceDistance(0.08); 
icp.setMaximumIterations(500); 
//icp.setTransformationEpsilon (0.000000000000000000001); 
icp.setTransformationEpsilon(1e-12); 
icp.setEuclideanFitnessEpsilon(1e-12); 
icp.setRANSACIterations(2000); 
icp.setRANSACOutlierRejectionThreshold(0.6);
```

I have tried all kinds of values in the options of ICP but with no success.

The code I use to create the point cloud:

```
        int density = 1; 
        for (int y = 0; y < depthFrame.getHeight(); y = y + density) { 
            for (int x = 0; x < depthFrame.getWidth(); x = x + density) { 
                short z = pDepthRow[y * depthVideoMode.getResolutionX() + x]; 
                if (z > 0 && z < depthStream.getMaxPixelValue()) { 
                        cloud_src->points[counter].x = x; 
                        cloud_src->points[counter].y = y; 
                        cloud_src->points[counter].z = z; 
                } 
            } 
        }
```

Any chance somebody can help me out configuring ICP?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, PCL uses meters as a unit of measurement. so, is it  intended that leaf size for downsampling is 6*6*6 !? I think it's huge !!
Try with some lower values and if it didn't work either, try ICP with the most simple configuration as follows :

```
 pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ> icp; 
 icp.setInputCloud(tgt); 
 icp.setInputTarget(src); 
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> Final; 
 icp.align(Final);
```

once, you got this working (and it should be), then start tuning the other parameters and it shouldn't be that hard to do.

Hope that helps, Cheers!

Comment: I know I use a rather large value for the leaves but when I use a value below 1 the clouds aren't down sampled. I also tried to cut out all the unnecessary code and just use the essentials like you suggest but unfortunately that didn't help. Any other suggestions are more than welcome! :)